# Checking the if current player has won the game of Tic Tac Toe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, tic-tac-toe

I am making a simple Tic Tac Toe with html CSS and JavaScript. No computer AL player implemented. Just two players taking turns. My checkWinner function is not working and I have no clue how to determine a winner. Somebody suggested that I create two dimensional array to store winning combinations which I did in a variable called winCombos. I am looping through all of them and comparing against the currentPlayer at different locations of cells array but it is not working. Probably I am doing it completely wrong. Can somebody please help me. Thanks

```js
var player1 = "X";
var player2 = "O";
var cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
var currentPlayer = player1;
var winner = "";
var winCombos = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];

function checkWinner(arr, curPlayer){
    arr.forEach(function(subArr){
      var counter = 0;
      subArr.forEach(function(elem){
        if(cells[elem] === curPlayer){
          counter++;
          if(counter == 2 ){
            winner = curPlayer;
            alert(winner);
          }
        }
      });
    });
}

function move(e){
  if(e.target.className === "cell" && e.target.textContent === ""){
    e.target.textContent = currentPlayer;
    checkWinner(winCombos, currentPlayer);
    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer === player1)?player2:player1;
  }
  
}

document.querySelector(".board").addEventListener("click", move);
```

```css
.container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 480px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.board{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.board .cell{
  width: 118px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    
   <div class="board">
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things: Use `innerHTML` to get the content of the div, not a string containing the whole div. Also check if there's actually 3 in a row, not just 2. (or you can move the `counter++;` to after the check, and leave it with `counter == 2`)

```
if(cells[elem].innerHTML === curPlayer){
  counter++;
  if(counter == 3 ){
    winner = curPlayer;
    alert(winner);
  }
}
```

```js
var player1 = "X";
var player2 = "O";
var cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
var currentPlayer = player1;
var winner = "";
var winCombos = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];

function checkWinner(arr, curPlayer){
    arr.forEach(function(subArr){
      var counter = 0;
      subArr.forEach(function(elem){
        if(cells[elem].innerHTML === curPlayer){
          counter++;
          if(counter == 3 ){
            winner = curPlayer;
            alert(winner);
          }
        }
      });
    });
}

function move(e){
  if(e.target.className === "cell" && e.target.textContent === ""){
    e.target.textContent = currentPlayer;
    checkWinner(winCombos, currentPlayer);
    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer === player1)?player2:player1;
  }
  
}

document.querySelector(".board").addEventListener("click", move);
```

```css
.container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 480px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.board{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.board .cell{
  width: 118px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    
   <div class="board">
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
     <div class="cell"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you much for your quick reply. It really helped. One thing though when I clicked third in a row the "X" or "O" appear after the alert. Can you please explain whats going on?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it's about chrome queueing up redraws and console logs. Perhaps it enqueues most things but treats alerts as interrupts? It might be worth asking another question

Comment: OK, Thanks for your help.